# Capture "updater" action from AngularUI's Bootstrap Typeahead

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

How can I capture the "updater" event from [AngularUI](http://angular-ui.github.io/)'s [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap) directive?

I've defined my HTML:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" class="span6" placeholder="8675309" ng-model="empid" typeahead="entry for entry in httpEmpIdSearch($viewValue, 8)">
```

... and my associated function:

```
$scope.httpEmpIdSearch = function(query, limit)
{
    return $http.get(
        '/visitorLog/api/v1/employee/?limit=' + limit + '&empid__startswith=' + query
    ).then(function(response)
    {
        output = [];

        angular.forEach(response.data.objects, function(value, key) {
            this.push(value.bems.toString());
        }, output);

        return output;
    });
}
```

I would like to take additional action (autocomplete a form) when the user clicks on an ID in the popup.  If raw Bootstrap I would use the "updater":

```
$('#sampleElement').typeahead({
  minLength: 3,
  source: function (query, process) 
  {
    // get the data
  },
  updater: function (item)
  {
    // user clicked on an item, do something more!
  },
});
```

I've tried various listeners like:

```
$scope.$on('typeahead-updated', function(event)
{ ... }
```

But I've not way to let me capture such an event.  Is there some way I can take additional action once a typeahead option is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not appear that there is a way to hook into that event in the directive. You could however put a watch on the model value and simulate this behavior.

Check out this plunker [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/KRQVNmRcnMY0Ek0j1heS?p=preview)

Since you are pulling the list of data from the server on the fly this solution may not work for you. But I would definitely have a look at watch it seems like the best way to achieve the desired outcome.

Something along these lines could work.

```
$scope.output = [];
$scope.httpEmpIdSearch = function(query, limit)
{
    return $http.get(
        '/visitorLog/api/v1/employee/?limit=' + limit + '&empid__startswith=' + query
    ).then(function(response)
    {
        $scope.output.length = 0;

        angular.forEach(response.data.objects, function(value, key) {
            this.push(value.bems.toString());
        }, $scope.output);

        return $scope.output;
    });
}

$scope.$watch('empid', function(newValue, oldValue){
    if(newValue !== oldValue && $scope.output.indexOf(newValue) !== -1){
       //do work here
    }
});
```

Comment: A good workaround for the current limitation in the library.  Thank you for the tip and example!

Answer (score 5):

Also, in version 0.4.0 of the ui-bootstrap library the `typeahead-on-select` directive is now supported. This should provide your desired event.

See: 
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/91ac17c9ed691a99647b66b3f464e3585398be19

Answer (score 0):

The full list of typeahead related directives is here:

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/typeahead/docs

typeahead-editable, typeahead-input-formatter, typeahead-loading, typeahead-min-length, typeahead-on-select, typeahead-template-url, typeahead-wait-ms